# How to limit range of random port sockets?

Tags: networking, kernel, tcp, socket, sysctl

There's a binary that I need to run which uses `bind` with a port argument of zero, to get a random free port from the system. Is there a way I can constrain the range of ports the kernel is allowed to pick from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

on Linux, you'd do something like

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="60000 61000"
```

instruction for changing ephemeral port range on other unices can be found for example at http://www.ncftp.com/ncftpd/doc/misc/ephemeral_ports.html

Answer (score 6):

If you want to change the way a binary runs without having access to its sources, you can sometimes use a shim, a piece of code that, in your example, will replace the call on `bind()` by a call to a function you provide that can manipulate the data before calling the real function.  See `LD_PRELOAD` in `man ld.so`.

Here's some C that does exactly that, shim_bind.c, overriding the port to 7777, and assuming an AF_INET socket. Compile it with `gcc -Wall -O2 -fpic -shared -ldl -o shim_bind.so shim_bind.c` and use it by putting `LD_PRELOAD=shim_bind.so` in front of your command.

```
/*
 * capture calls to a routine and replace with your code
 * http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/305336/119298
 * gcc -Wall -O2 -fpic -shared -ldl -o shim_bind.so shim_bind.c
 * LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/shim_bind.so ./test
 */
#define _GNU_SOURCE /* needed to get RTLD_NEXT defined in dlfcn.h */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen){
    static int (*real_bind)(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr,
                            socklen_t addrlen) = NULL;
    int port = 7777;
    struct sockaddr_in theaddr;

    if (!real_bind) {
        real_bind = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "bind");
        char *error = dlerror();
        if (error != NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "binding: port %d\n", port);
    memcpy(&theaddr, addr, sizeof(theaddr));
    theaddr.sin_port = htons((unsigned short)port);
    return real_bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&theaddr, addrlen);
}
```

Comment: The `ip_local_port_range` will be easier for me to set up right now, but I'll probably need to play with other calls on this binary so this looks very useful, thanks!